# Counting Spanning Trees with Roots of Unity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory, trees

In a paper by Kenyon, Propp and Wilson, the [number of spanning trees in a certain graph in the hexagonal lattice](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903025) is:

$$ \prod_{a,b,c} (3 - a-b-c)^{1/6}$$

where $a^{3n}=1, (a/b)^n=1,abc=1$ and $a,b,c$ are distinct.

In between the lines, the paper says this product is an integer.

---

I tried to program it Mathematica

```
Product[
(3 - e[k/(3 n)] - e[(k + 3 l)/(3 n)] - e[(-2 k - 3 l)/(3 n)])^(1/6)
, {k, 1, 3 n}, {l, 1, n - 1}];
```

The result is a real number but not an integer.

---

In mathematical terms I wrote:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{3n} \prod_{l=1}^{n-1} (3-\omega^k- \omega^{k+3l}- \omega^{-2k-3l}) $$
where $\omega = e^{2\pi i /3n} = \cos \frac{2\pi}{3n} + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{3n}$ but this number has significant figures pas the decimal point.

How do I (correctly) parameterize the product in $a,b,c$ ?

---

**Response to comments**:

- it looks like we need $k \neq l, 2l \mod n$ and $l \neq 0 \mod n$.
- the Galois action seems to be $(a,b,c) \mapsto (\omega a , \omega b, \omega^{-2} c)$.  Shouldn't the sum be Galois invariant even if $a,b,c$ are not always distinct?
- people who'd had not trouble with it, can you share your code?

Comment: Incidentally, if you are not convinced that it is an integer, it definitely is. It is a product of algebraic integers which is fixed under the action of the appropriate Galois group.

Comment: Which integer is it?  I am using Mathematica, but I'm not getting an integer.  Something's wrong.

Comment: The $\mathbb{Z}/3n\mathbb{Z}$ Galois group shifts the variables: $a \mapsto \omega a, b \mapsto \omega b, c \mapsto \omega^{-2}c$.

Comment: Your expression is missing the requirement that $c$ be distinct from $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I get $1, 1, 3, 26, 620, 40071, 6957314, 3228498000, 3990904966161, 13112285327130880, \ldots$.  It doesn't seem to be in the OEIS yet.

Comment: $k = k + 3l \mod 3n$ means $l = 0 \mod n$, $k = -2k -3l \mod 3n$ means $k=l \mod n$ and $k + 3l = -2k - 3l \mod 3n$ means $k + 2l =0 \mod n$.
Shouldn't the sum be Galois invariant even if $a,b,c$ are not always distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maple:

> F := proc(n)
>
> local P,w,i,j,k;
>
> P:= 1;
>
> for i from 0 to 3*n-1 do
>
> ```
> for j from 0 to 3*n-1 do
>
>   if (i - j) mod 3 <> 0 then next end if;
>
>   k:= (-i - j) mod (3*n);
>
>   if nops({i,j,k}) <> 3 then next end if;
>
>   P:= P * (3-w^i - w^j - w^k);
> ```
>
> end do end do;
>
> P:=simplify(P,{numtheory:-cyclotomic(3*n,w)=0});
>
> simplify(P^(1/6))
>
> end proc;

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica... it might look something like this

```
P = 1;
Do[
   Do[
       If[Mod[i - j, 3] != 0, k = Mod[-i - j , 3 n],];
       If[Mod[i - j, 3] != 0 && Length[DeleteDuplicates[{i, j, k}]] < 3, , 
           P = P*(3 - w^i - w^j - w^k )]
       , {j, 0, 3 n - 1}]
   , {i, 0, 3 n - 1}]
PolynomialMod[P, w^(3 n) - 1]
Replace[%, w -> E^(2 Pi I / 3/n)]
```